How to use pixi.js to extract canvas with background colour
I'm working with this GitHub project: Arcada.
I've modified the export button to extract the floor map from the canvas. However, the exported image has a black/transparent background instead of the set background color.
I've set the background color during the app initialization, and it displays correctly when running the app:
        // On first render create our application
    const app = new Application({
        view: document.getElementById("pixi-canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement,
        resolution: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        autoDensity: true,
        //backgroundColor: 0xebebeb,
        backgroundColor: 0x2980b9, // Set background color to something
        antialias: true,
        resizeTo: window
    });

I added a function to extract the floor map from the canvas, but it doesn't include the background color in the exported image:
    public captureCanvasAsJPG(callback: (blob: Blob) => void) {
    let opts: IRendererOptionsAuto = {
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
        //backgroundColor: 0x2980b9 // Set the background color to 
    };

    let renderer = autoDetectRenderer(opts);
    renderer.render(this);
    renderer.backgroundColor = 0x2980b9;

    renderer.plugins.extract.canvas(this).toBlob((blob) => {
        if (blob) {
            callback(blob);
        } else {
            console.error("Failed to convert canvas to blob.");
        }
    }, "image/jpeg");
}

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to ensure the background color is included in the exported image?
Thanks!
